# which one is good practice: using block of code in main or making function of same code?

Tags: c, function

Actually what i want to know is that should i use function oftenly  for short code or put it inside main
for e.g

```
main() {
    //something something
    if(condition)i++;   //This is the code for which i want to make function
}
```

Or should I use it like this

```
void incrementi() {
    i++;
    return;
}

main() {
    //something something  
}
```

Which method is fast to execute, readable or in short what is good practice?

Comment: depends if you would reuse the function or not

Comment: yeah @nathanhayfield using it many times but i can also write that code wherever i want,but what want to know is that which one is faster method?

Comment: `incrementi` would be an astoundingly bad function since it actually acts on a global variable (a bad sign in itself) and just obscures a built in operator. Do you have a more realistic scenario?

Comment: Also, I assume that this is C - if it is, please edit your question and add that tag. If it isn't, please edit your question and add an *appropriate* language tag.

Comment: Write code to be legible, not fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, the code being done only by a condition and an increase, I advise you not to write a function but bring back the line of code whenever you need. If you had more instructions, it is advisable to create a function to call every time you need then reusing that piece of code

Answer (score 1):

Simone Pesotto has given the right answer. But I would like to explain the reason. Everytime a function is called, an **Activation Record** is created and placed on the programming stack, alongwith details of calling function, pointers to it, parameters passed, details of the called function, etc. This obviously takes time. Instead, something as simple as an increment operation takes only one machine instruction which is far cheaper than creating a separate function. So functions are made when:

1. A big operation is to be done
2. The operation is repeated numerous times in the program

I hope this answer helps in enhancing your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

i++ is a function that increments a variable, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: yeah i want to know which one is faster way:creating function or simply writing in main??

Comment: Writing in main, you have to create a stack in the memory for the function